# Why do KivMob Test ads show but my ads don't in Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy, admob

I'm trying to show real ads with KivMob in my mobile kivy application (python)

I've created

1. An AdMob account
2. A new app
3. An ad unit (interstitial)
4. A test device in AdMob (with an add recognizer i found in google settings in this device)

In my python code I then call these functions:

```
self.ads = KivMob('my publisher id')
self.ads.add_test_device('my device id') # 16 characters long?
self.ads.new_interstitial('my interstitial add unit id')
```

Then when i need to show the add I simply do:

```
self.ads.request_interstitial()
self.ads.show_interstitial()
```

This particular code works perfect when I use KivMob's TestIds like this

```
self.ads = KivMob(TestIds.APP)
self.ads.new_interstitial(TestIds.INTERSTITIAL)
```

instead of my ids

```
self.ads = KivMob('my publisher id')
self.ads.add_test_device('my device id') # 16 characters long?
self.ads.new_interstitial('my interstitial add unit id')
```

If i specify those id's no ads show up. Why is that? Am I doing something wrong?